# Fixing A Gradle dependsOn Deprecation Warning

Tags: gradle

I upgraded my build environment to the most recent version of gradle (1.0-rc3).  I'm receiving the following deprecation warning:

***"The Project.dependsOn(String path) method has been deprecated"***

I fixed all of my task dependsOn references to use the object references, but I do not know how to fix the dependsOn references for multiproject Projects.  I have a project that depends on another project.  This is the definition at the top of the build.gradle script:

```
dependsOn(':projects/arch/application')
```

How do I convert this string reference to an object reference to the project?  I looked through the gradle documentation, but it still references the deprecated string syntax (link below).

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

This syntax works today, but the deprecation warning is telling me it will not in the future.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The deprecation warning isn't about changing String references to Object references (there isn't even a `Project.dependsOn()` method that accepts an Object). It's about giving up on `Project.dependsOn()` and only using `Task.dependsOn()`.

In Gradle, execution dependencies are always between tasks. `Project.dependsOn()` was a way to add a task dependency from every task in project A to the equally named task in project B (if it exists). Practice showed that this feature has little value and is often misunderstood, hence the deprecation.

Comment: That explanation makes sense, I understand now, thank you.  I moved that dependsOn call to a task instead of using it at the project level and it solved the issue.